# Can not prevent accessing to a specific route using $routeChangeStart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing

In angular js I have a routing function that should manage access to routes for admin and non admin users so i used to `$routeChangeStart` achieve that according to my logic if a user is logged in he can not go to that rout `'/'` (which is log in page ). but that dose not work. it still can go to login if the URL matches `http://localhost:3000/#/`

```
app.run(['$rootScope', 'authService', '$location', function($rootScope, authService, $location){
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(evt, next, curr){

        if(authService.AccessPrivilegesAuth()){
            if(!authService.AccessPrivilegesAdmin(next.access_level)){
                $location.path('categories');
            }

        }else if(authService.AccessPrivilegesAuth()== false){
            $location.path('/');
        }
    })
}]);
```

her is the log in controller.

```
app.controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$location', 'authService','$cookieStore', function($scope, $location, authService, $cookieStore){
     $scope.loginData = {
         EmailAddress : "",
         password : ""
     };

     $scope.error; $scope.error_exist = false; 
     $scope.login = function(){
         authService.Login($scope.loginData).success(function(response){
             $cookieStore.put('AuthorizationHeader', response.Token);
             authService.isAuth = true;
             authService.IsAdmin = response.IsAdmin;
             var authData = $cookieStore.get('AuthorizationHeader');
             console.log(authData);
             $location.path('categories');
         }).error(function(Error){
             $scope.error_exist = true;
             switch(Error.ExceptionMessage){
                case "201" :
                     $scope.error = "The emailAddress/password pair don't match an existing member"; break;
                case "210" :
                     $scope.error = "Value cannot be null missing Email Address and/or password."; break;
                case "202" :
                     $scope.error = "The email address you are using isn't confirmed. Please see your inbox for further instructions."; break;
                default : 
                     $scope.error = "Error with the server";
             }
         });

     };
 }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$routeChangeStart` has `preventDefault()` but from what I remember it didn't work. However some time ago I managed to get it working with `$locationChangeStart`.

`$locationChangeStart` fires before `$routeChangeStart` and if it is prevented, `$routeChangeStart` doesn't fire at all.

Note that I haven't tested this code:

```
$rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function(event) {
    if(notAllowed){
        event.preventDefault();
    };
});
```

Comment: so you want me to combine $locationChangeStart and $routeChangeStart ?

Comment: @user2918388 You should use $locationChangeStart instead of $routeChangeStart

Comment: Worked only if i open developer tools in chrome! dose resolve has problem with that